# Complicated comprehension of the sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, literature

> In his heart every man knows quite well that, being unique, he will be in the world only once and that no imaginable chance will for a second time gather together into a unity so strangely variegated an assortment as he is: he knows it but hides it like a bad conscience. - quoted from 'Untimely Meditation" by Friedrich Nietzsche

It is complicated for me to understand what he is talking about. There is no imaginable chance to be in the world for a second time or something?

Comment: I think you have got the meaning.

Comment: Wow, what a whopper of a sentence! Your quote is cut off; you might want to add the remaining "... as he is: he knows it but hides it like a bad conscience." And you're on the right track. It's a really long-winded way to say "there will never be another person exactly like him."

Comment: You have asked 17 questions on this site, but accepted none of the answers you have received. Some of your questions have very good answers to them, case in point: scroll down. Please consider accepting and (when you have enough rep) upvoting good answers. You should give feedback to the answers other people go out of their way to write for you.

Answer (score 3):

Let us break it down. I have added the concluding part provided by Type1A in a comment

> In his heart every man knows quite well that, being unique, he will be in the world only once

That part is clear enough. We all know that we are unique and only live once.

> and that no imaginable chance will for a second time gather together into a unity so strangely variegated an assortment as he is

So there is no way that chance will gather together the assortment of pieces which make us up and make a new human out of them.

> he knows it but hides it like a bad conscience

Clear enough I think.

I would remark that this is a very complicated sentence and is a translation from the German. Some of the difficulty may be that the translator was trying too hard to reproduce the complexities of the language used by Nietschze.